# Django - Left join parent and child tables?

Tags: python, django, orm, left-join

I am trying to do a left join with the least number of database queries.

I have looked into using .select_related, I have tried a raw query and tried to see if it could be done with Q.

I would like to retrieve all States and linked Cities if any are listed.

Models.py

```
class State(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
  abbreviation = models.CharField(max_length=2)

  def __str__(self):
    return str(self.id)


class City(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
  population = models.IntegerField()
  state = models.ForeignKey(State, related_name="cities", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

  def __str__(self):
    return str(self.id)
```

State

| ID | Name | Abbreviation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Texas | TX |
| 2 | California | CA |
| 3 | Illinois | IL |

City

| ID | Name | Population | State |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Los Angeles | 3769485 | 2 |
| 2 | Dallas | 1259404 | 1 |
| 3 | Houston | 2264876 | 1 |

Desired result (State columns then City columns)

| ID | Name | Abbreviation | ID | Name | Population | State |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Texas | TX | 2 | Dallas | 1259404 | 1 |
| 1 | Texas | TX | 3 | Houston | 2264876 | 1 |
| 2 | California | CA | 1 | Los Angeles | 3769485 | 2 |
| 3 | Illinois | IL |  |  |  |  |

Problem Using .select_related:

```
cities_states = City.objects.all().select_related('state').order_by('state_id')
```

Using .select_related does not give me any States (e.g. Illinois) that do not have a City

Problem Using RawQuery:

```
sql = '''
SELECT S.*, C.* 
FROM "state" S
LEFT JOIN "city" C
ON (S."id" = C."state_id") 
ORDER BY S."id" ASC
'''

cities_states = State.objects.raw(sql)

for obj in cities_states:
  print(obj)
```

The RawQuery returns the data I need but I don't know how to retrieve the specific field from a specific table.
For example: print(obj.name) will give me the State name and print(obj.id) will give me State Id.

How do I pull only a City Name or City Id if both State table and City table each have a "name"  and "id" field?

How do I obtain the data with least number of database calls?

How do I differentiate same-name column names (e.g. id, name) of tables when using raw queries?

Comment: Well the query itself to repeat the state is often *not* a good idea. You can use `State.objects.prefetch_related('cities')`, to do this in two queries.

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression where you don't get what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]--then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your desired result is often not optimal. Indeed, it will here *repeat* the data for the `State` every time, making the result from the database much larger, and potentially also increases memory usage by Django *a lot*.

To counter that, Django provides [**`.prefetch_related(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) which will make two queries, the first one for the data for the `State`s, and then fetch the related `City`s and do the JOINing in Django/Python.

We thus can query with:

```
states = State.objects.prefetch_related('cities')
for state in states:
    print(f'for {state}')
    for city in state.cities.all():
        print(f' - {city}')
```